# Title and mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I am css beginner and I have got a little problem. I have created header with  title in it. The title name consists from 2 parts. First part is just text, but second part is the text with background. I wanted to create a title which would change text color and background on :hover. However, if you hover over the title from right side everything works perfect, but from the left no.

Here is my code

```css
#rus {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 5px;
}

#rus:hover {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: red;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

h1 {
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  clear: both;
}

#site-title {
  margin-right: 270px;
  padding: 3em 0 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

#site-title a {
  color: #111;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#site-title a:hover,
#site-title a:focus,
#site-title a:active {
  color: #1982d1;
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
  <h1 id="site-title">
    <a href="#" rel="home">Bundesliga 
      <span id="rus">RUS</span>
    </a>
  </h1>
</hgroup>
```

As you can see the span tag placed into link tag. If I hover from right side it affects both link tag and span, because in any case mouse is over link tag. But from the right side mouse hover touches only link tag and span is not affected.
What should I change to make the whole title to change its CSS properties on mouse hover?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to when you say "title"?

Comment: Please include all relevant code.  You're missing opening tags as well as CSS related to the title you reference.

Comment: I am sorry guys It is first time I am posting here.

Comment: <hgroup>
<h1 id="site-title">     
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">Бундеслига 
<span id="rus">RUS</span>
</a>    
</h1>
<h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</hgroup>

Comment: #site-title {
 margin-right: 270px;
 padding: 3em 0 0;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

#site-description {
 color: #7a7a7a;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 8px 0 2.5em;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#rus {
 
 background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 5px;
 
}

#rus:hover {
 
 background: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: red;
    padding: 4px 5px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 
 
}

Comment: Sorry there is a problem with formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code.  Can you edit your question to include it there?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with your code and it appears to be working correctly.  Can you confirm?  https://jsfiddle.net/5j5nscu7/

Comment: Yes I have checked, the code you recreated is true!

Comment: What I'm saying is that the problem you describe doesn't seem to exist in the code you supplied.

Comment: I am so sorry it is my first time here and I cannot format the code on my message. What if I show you that web-page on the Net?

Comment: Use jsFiddle for it. I'll update your question.

Comment: Here is my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8886oab6/5/

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is move the `:hover` from your span to the parent `a`:

```css
#rus {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}

a:hover #rus {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: red;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

h1 {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    clear: both;
}

#site-title {
    margin-right: 270px;
    padding: 3em 0 0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

#site-title a {
    color: #111;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site-title a:hover,
#site-title a:focus,
#site-title a:active {
    color: #1982d1;
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
  <h1 id="site-title">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">Bundesliga 
      <span id="rus">RUS</span>
    </a>
  </h1>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: For better understanding my trouble have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/8886oab6/5/
If you hover a mouse from right side it changes the color of text and background. But from left side it changes the color of ONLY "Bundesliga" word. "RUS" and red background are not affected. The idea is to change color of whole text and background color on mouse hover.

Comment: Yep. You need to replace `#rus:hover` with `a:hover #rus`, Here's your [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/8886oab6/6/)

Comment: Updated answer to match your code and updated your question with your code example. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your time! Just one theoretical question. Does a:hover affect all selectors/id/classes that is going after? For example if I put #b1 .tube after a:hover they also change color or property values?

Comment: A `CSS` selector applies a rule in the brackets to any matched element if it is the strongest (most specific) selector specified for the rule. So, yes: `a:hover` will apply to any hovered `<a>` element, unless stronger selectors specify otherwise for the element being hovered. To determine what applies at one particular moment you can use element inspector in any major browser, which will also allow you to specify states for the element, including hover. It will show you what rules apply and where they are defined. Rules defined but not applying are shown, typically stroked or grayed out.